# Android - Launch Intent as new app

Tags: android, android-intent, media-player, background-process

Is it possible to launch an Intent as a new application?

**Wanted behaviour:**

- The user clicks a button in my app.
- The media player Intent is launched and plays the desired media.
- The user long-press the **home button**. In this menu, I would like to see **both** the media player and my app. I would like the user to be able to listen to the music
  using his desired media player and being able to put my app in foreground.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure as I've never used it, but I guess you could use the intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for this.

```
Intent intent = your intent;
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for more info.

Cheers

Comment: I've already tried that and I don't see both apps when long-pressing the home button.